# MySQL LEFT JOIN - How to handle cases where records have no match with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML table populated with records returned from MySQL `LEFT JOIN`.

This works, but I need to handle records that do not have a match in the `JOIN`.  Currently, the HTML table is like the illustration below, and unit_outcome records that are unmatched sit in a cell with no corresponding program_outcome.

```
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| program_outcome                  |  unit_outcome                                    |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                  | unit_outcome 5, unit_outcome 7                   |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| program outcome 1                | unit_outcome 2, unit_outcome 4                   |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| program outcome 2                | unit_outcome 1, unit_outcome 3, unit_outcome 6   |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

That in itself is OK, but I want to add in the currently blank program_outcome cell a string like "No matching program outcome."  I would like to do that in the PHP in my code, but not sure how to handle that:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(unit.unit_pk) AS unit_pk,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<strong>',unit.unit_code,': </strong>', unit_outcome.unit_outcome) SEPARATOR '|') unit_outcomes,
       MAX(program_outcome.program_outcome) program_outcome,
       GROUP_CONCAT(unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk) unit_outcome_pks, 
       program_outcome.program_outcome_pk,
       program_outcome.program_outcome
FROM unit
LEFT JOIN unit_unit_outcome_lookup
    ON unit_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_fk = unit.unit_pk
LEFT JOIN unit_outcome
    ON unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk = unit_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_outcome_fk
LEFT JOIN program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup
    ON program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_outcome_fk = unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk
LEFT JOIN program_outcome
    ON program_outcome.program_outcome_pk = program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup.program_outcome_fk
GROUP BY program_outcome_pk ORDER BY cast(program_outcome as unsigned) ASC";

$result = $connection->query( $query );

echo "<table width='100%' border='1'><thead><tr><th>Program Outcomes</th><th>Unit Outcomes</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['program_outcome'] . "</td><td>" . str_replace('|', '<p>',$row['unit_outcomes']) . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "<tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Using php you can say if program_outcome is null then Replace with whatevere string you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the SQL using `IFNULL()`.

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(unit.unit_pk) AS unit_pk,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<strong>',unit.unit_code,': </strong>', unit_outcome.unit_outcome) SEPARATOR '|') unit_outcomes,
       MAX(program_outcome.program_outcome) program_outcome,
       GROUP_CONCAT(unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk) unit_outcome_pks, 
       program_outcome.program_outcome_pk,
       IFNULL(program_outcome.program_outcome, 'No matching program outcome.') AS program_outcome
FROM unit
LEFT JOIN unit_unit_outcome_lookup
    ON unit_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_fk = unit.unit_pk
LEFT JOIN unit_outcome
    ON unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk = unit_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_outcome_fk
LEFT JOIN program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup
    ON program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_outcome_fk = unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk
LEFT JOIN program_outcome
    ON program_outcome.program_outcome_pk = program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup.program_outcome_fk
GROUP BY program_outcome_pk ORDER BY cast(program_outcome as unsigned) ASC";
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I had just to think about the PHP side for 90 seconds and easily worked it out. Funny how sometimes problems can appear bigger than they really are!  Your solution in the MySQL is cleaner though!